# in c I cant find a cubic equation solution using binary exploration

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    double x, X, XX, max = 1e9, min = -1e9;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    X = max;
    x = (max + min) / 2;
    XX = min;

    while (1)
    {
        if (a*x*x*x + b * x*x + c * x + d < 0)
        {
            max = X;
            min = x;
            x = (max + x) / 2;

        }
        else if ((a*x*x*x+b * x*x+c *x+d) <= 0.0001 && (a*x*x*x+b * x*x+c *x+d) >=-0.0001)
        {
        printf("%.3d\n\n", x);
        break;
        }
        else
        {
            max = x;
            min = XX;
            x = (x + min) / 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I would like to use binary exploration to find a program that seeks an increasing number of trigonometric solutions to the third decimal point with a range of -1e9 to 1e9 in c language. but i cant find a answer..and The margin of error is 10^4.

Comment: Your ifs look out of order. Suggestion: calculate the expression once (`double value = a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d;`) and use that value where needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

- The `return 0` is the last statement of the loop, which means that you don't loop at all. Make it the last statement of the function. (That's probably why you print before you break.)
- Your print statement should use one of the printing formats for floating-point numbers: `%e`, `%f` or `%g`. (Your coefficients should probably be floating-point numbers, too.)
- Your `X` and `XX` never change from the original values. Therefore, when you set `min` or `max` to these values, you don't really narrow your search interval. You don't need these values and you only need to adjust one boundary of your interval: If you want to search in the left interval, make `max = x` and leave `min` intact.
- Your binary exploration logic will only work if `a > 0`. Your program could enforce that by dividing all coefficiants by `a`. (If `a == 0`, you have a parabola and might not get any real solutions.)
- Commenter pmg's suggestions are also valid: You should probably test whether you are in the desired range first. And not writing out the whole expression will make the code more readable.

Here's how the code might look:

```
x = (max + min) / 2;

while (1) {
    double z = a * x*x*x + b * x*x + c * x + d;

    if (fabs(z) < 0.0001) break;

    if (z < 0) {
        min = x;
        x = (max + x) / 2;
    } else {
        max = x;
        x = (x + min) / 2;
    }
}

printf("%g\n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a cubic, I do not see this algorithm as certainly converging even with `a > 0`.  Any point in the iteration  when `f(min), f(max)` are on the same side of 0.0, answer may not converge.

A better first step for a *cubic* is to find the 2 values x1,x2, where `f'(x) == 0.0`.  Given `a,b,c,d`, solve `3*a*a*x^2 + 2*b*x + c == 0`.  See [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Then `f(x) == 0.0` may exist in the [min...x1] [x1...x2] [x2..max] ranges.

For each sub-range range, see if the endpoints cross 0.0.  If they do, then apply bi-section